# Call Scrapy / Scrapyrt with web form

Tags: web, scrapy

I'm trying to make a web form that calls a `scrapy` using `scrapyrt`. but I come up against a problem: when I send the command it goes to the end, I mean, when I close the broswer, the spider stop.

Does anyone know something I can implement a web form by calling a spider?

thank you all.

Comment: You need a scheduler not a scrapyrt in that case. Use scrapyd to launch a server and then call the scrapyd api through your form

Answer (score 0):

ScrapyD can fulfill your requirement. [Here is how to install it](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#installing-scrapyd-in-ubuntu)

Once installed, go into your Scrapy's project root folder, and run `scrapyd-deploy`, it will deploy your project on ScrapyD.

Then do this command to run your scraper.

```
http://localhost:6800/schedule.json?project=default&spider=yourspidername
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to follow a few steps, but I stopped in the following message in the browser: "message": "Expected one of [b'HEAD ', b'object', b'POST ']"}

My link: http://localhost:6800/schedule.json?Project=webcoleta&spider=toysrus

I did not find anything about it.
I already thank you

Comment: What link you access in browser? Try project=default

Comment: Also the same error message in the browser. If you run the CMD command the http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project = web browser -d spider=toysrus is ok.